# Is every smooth function Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, differential-geometry

Is every function of [class $C^∞$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness) also (locally) [Lipschitz continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity)? If so, how can this be proven?

Comment: Lipschitz implies a linear growth of the function, which is pretty strong. You can easily imagine a smooth function which is not, the exponential function for example. Smoothness only implies locally Lipschitz.

Comment: Sorry, I meant locally Lipschitz continuous. I have edited the question to reflect this intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in fact, every $C^1$ function is locally Lipchitz. This is because there is an interval around every $x$ where $f'(x)$ exists and is bounded; the bound on $f'(x)$ will be the Lipchitz constant in this neighborhood.