# Are all smooth functions Lipschitz?

Tags: functions, lipschitz-functions

Can we prove the following statement:
 $$\|\triangledown f(x)-\triangledown f(y)\|\leq\beta\|x-y\|\xrightarrow{?} \| f(x)-f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$$
i.e. every smooth function is Lipschitz? If it is not correct please tell me under what conditions it can be correct.

---

In the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974611/is-every-smooth-function-lipschitz-continuous) an example is given that exponential function is smooth and is not Lipschitz. However I can't find any $\beta$ such that $\|e^x-e^y\|\leq \beta\|x-y\|$ and derivative of exponential equals to itself!

Comment: Consider $f(x) = x^2$ there is no $L$ such that $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R, |f(x) - f(y)| \le L |x-y|$

Comment: It is true, however, that smooth functions are locally Lipschitz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smooth functions are [locally Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200637/locally-continuously-differentiable-implies-locally-lipschitz). In general, they are not globally Lipschitz: for example, 
$$
e^{x+1}-e^x = e^x(e-1) \to \infty\  \text{ as }\ x\to\infty 
$$
which shows there is no bound $|e^y-e^x|\le C|y-x|$.  A similar computation can be made with $f(x) = x^2$.

Under the additional assumption that the derivative is bounded, the function is Lipschitz. This is a direct consequence of the Mean Value Theorem: see 
[Bounded derivative implies Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2116480), for example.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What about the converse? Is every lipschitz function whose derivative exist $\beta$-smooth?

Comment: Didn't find anything. :(

Comment: [Lipschitz implies bounded derivative?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1013550)